# Replacing first three characters with 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, validation, replace

I am removing all the spaces from the string and also replacing `+61` with `0`. I am checking if the first three characters are `+61` then replace it with `0`

The code is below which is working fine

```
 function updateMobileNumber() {
    var updatedMobileValue = visibleField.val().replace(/\s+/g, "");
    if (updatedMobileValue.charAt(0) === '+'&& 
        updatedMobileValue.charAt(1) === '6'&& 
        updatedMobileValue.charAt(2) === '1' ){
           updatedMobileValue = updatedMobileValue.replace('+61', '0');
     }
    console.log(updatedMobileValue);
 }
```

Is there any efficient way to do this.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're using `.replace` once already to remove spaces, try using `.replace` again to replace `+61` at the start of the string with `0`:

```
function updateMobileNumber() {
  var updatedMobileValue = visibleField.val()
    .replace(/\s+/g, "")
    .replace(/^\+61/, '0');
  console.log(updatedMobileValue);
}
```

The `^` in the regular expression indicates that the position is at the start of the string, and the `\` before the `+` is needed because `+` is a character with a special meaning in a regular expression, so to indicate the literal plus sign, you have to escape it first.